# Is there a way to mark variables as constant / unchangeable in pyright?

Tags: python, type-hinting, pyright

I tried googling but I haven't come across a way to use a type annotation to mark a variable as constant in pyright. I think the type Constant is more like scalar constant rather than the C/C++ keyword `const`.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python 3.8, you can type-hint a variable as `Final`([API docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Final), [PEP591](https://peps.python.org/pep-0591/)), to determine that it should not be changed beyond this point.

```py
# type1.py
from typing import Final
foo: Final = 1
foo = 2 # raises an error
```

```bash
$ mypy type1.py --pretty
type1.py:3: error: Cannot assign to final name "foo"  [misc]
    foo = 2
    ^~~~~~~
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

You can also add more type information by enclosing the type in square brackets:
`bar: Final[float] = 2`